# Server side pagination in Azure ( MS SQL )

Tags: sql-server, azure, pagination

How to implement pagination in an SQL query in Azure 
To be specific , how to I specify limit and offset ....

I am supposed to show 50 records per page and there are like 4000 records in a database

I am writing an API for the same to fetch the records using an SQL query .... How to specify that in an MS SQL Query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  *  FROM 
yourtable  order by someuniquecolumn
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY ;
```

You also can use Variables  like below:

```
DECLARE 
  @pagenum  AS INT = 1,
  @pagesize AS INT = 10;

SELECT *
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY someuniquecolumns
OFFSET (@pagenum - 1) * @pagesize ROWS FETCH NEXT @pagesize ROWS ONLY;
```

**Since, this is getting more votes,Adding some more info about offset ,Fetch..**

Assume a table with 1000 rows,when you do `offset 800,fetch next 10 rows only`....Sql server will read first 800 rows and then only get next 10 rows..But with second approach,you will do exact seek ,with good indexes..

I watched this long back from a video of [Itzik Ben-Gan](https://tsql.lucient.com/booksdisplay/),but can't seem to find it now

**References:**
http://sqlmag.com/blog/sql-server-2012-t-sql-glance-offsetfetch

Comment: That Helped .. Thanks :)